# Unknown column 'customer' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a invoice script for my company, I now have alittle knowledge of PHP (especially manipulating existing files) and the programmer of the script is no longer avaliable, so I decided to extend the script with an offer list. This works exactly the same as the invoice script, only it uses a different table.

Now I'm getting the error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1054
>   Unknown column 'customer' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT idofferte,noofferte,CONCAT(namecustomer,' ',lastname)
     customer,DATE_FORMAT(dateofferte,'%d/%m/%Y')dateofferte,
     (SELECT SUM(pu*duration)
         FROM service2
         WHERE offerte=idofferte
      ) subtotal,discount,btw,transport,material
FROM offerte
INNER JOIN customer ON idcustomer=customer
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(noofferte,9) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 0,25
```

Original script (for invoice's):

```
function ilist( $start = 0, $limit = 25, $pattern = '' ) {
    $where = 'WHERE 1=1';
    if( '' != $pattern )
        $where .= " AND namecustomer LIKE '$pattern%' OR lastname LIKE '$pattern%'";
    return $this->db->query( "SELECT idinvoice,noinvoice,CONCAT(namecustomer,' ',lastname) customer,DATE_FORMAT(dateinvoice,'%d/%m/%Y')dateinvoice,(SELECT SUM(pu*duration) FROM service WHERE invoice=idinvoice)subtotal,discount,btw,transport,material FROM invoice INNER JOIN customer ON idcustomer=customer $where ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(noinvoice,9) AS UNSIGNED) DESC LIMIT $start,$limit" )->result_array();
}
```

Script by me (for offers):

```
function ilist( $start = 0, $limit = 25, $pattern = '' ) {
    $where = 'WHERE 1=1';
    if( '' != $pattern )
        $where .= " AND namecustomer LIKE '$pattern%' OR lastname LIKE '$pattern%'";
    return $this->db->query( "SELECT idofferte,noofferte,CONCAT(namecustomer,' ',lastname) customer,DATE_FORMAT(dateofferte,'%d/%m/%Y')dateofferte,(SELECT SUM(pu*duration) FROM service2 WHERE offerte=idofferte)subtotal,discount,btw,transport,material FROM offerte INNER JOIN customer ON idcustomer=customer $where ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(noofferte,9) AS UNSIGNED) DESC LIMIT $start,$limit" )->result_array();
}
```

The difference between my script and the original is the tables.
How can i solve this error?

NOTE: The error won't appear in the origninal script ofcourse.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
The tables:

```
-------------------------------
Invoice
-------------------------------
idinvoice
noinvoice
costumer
dateinvoice
discount
btw
transport
material
employee
creation

-------------------------------
Offerte
-------------------------------
idofferte
noofferte
customer
dateofferte
subjectofferte
discount
btw
transport
material
employee
creation

-------------------------------
customer
-------------------------------
idcustomer
namecustomer
lastname
address
number
zip
city
phone
email

-------------------------------
service
-------------------------------
idservice
dateservice
description
duration
pu
invoice

-------------------------------
service2
-------------------------------
idservice
dateservice
description
duration
pu
offerte
```

Comment: As the error says, the column "customer" does not exist.  What do your tables look like?

Comment: This error occures when the field (here 'customer') doesn't exist in the table. You'll have to alter your table to add this field. It's not a PHP error, but it's relative to your database structure.

Comment: I would recommend being explicit with your `JOIN` condition... `table1.column = table2.column`

Comment: it's right here:  `INNER JOIN customer ON idcustomer=customer  $where` you're using `customer` like it is a column but it's not... it probably needs to be something like `customer.idcustomer`, whatever that ID field is you need to join on.

Comment: With all chance, your `offerte` table has no `customer` column. Check your schema and update your queries accordingly.

Comment: @Izkata have 3 tables: Costumer, invoice and offer.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I'm really confused, why does it work with the original script then?

Comment: you changed the table... and the new one is different, i guess.  can you provide us with some table structure for the new table and the old table?  all the error means is that the column named `customer` doesn't exist in the query.  it must have belonged to the old table and the new table you used doesn't have one called `customer`.

Comment: You need to use aliasing for the tables and for the columns since its a join query.Or else use tablename itself as the aliasing while using the fields

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I updated the post with the tables!

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem.
I just realised i made an typo in database.
I wrote as column name: Costumer instead of customer.

Thanks everyone for your help!